# "blühen" im Sinne von "widerfahren"

Tags: meaning

Wie verwendet man das Verb "blühen" in der Bedeutung von "widerfahren". Kann man z.B. Folgendes sagen:

> Ihm blühte da ein Unfall.

Und was hat es außerdem mit dem folgenden Satz auf sich:

> Er wollte Abitur machen,aber plötzlich blühte ihm eine Karriere als Betonbauer.

Comment: Falsche Annahme: *blühen* hat außerhalb seines wörtlichen Sinns nie die Bedeutung "widerfahren" - Sondern höchstens "drohen" oder "bevorstehen". Der Duden sagt zwar "widerfahren", das halte ich aber für Unsinn. canoo z.B. weiß es besser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Ihm blühte da ein Unfall.
>   (Variation von *»Da blühte ihm ein Unfall.«* oder von *»Ihm blühte hier/dort ein Unfall.«*)
>
> Er wollte Abitur machen, aber plötzlich blühte ihm eine Karriere als
>   Betonbauer.

Das sind grammatikalisch richtige, jedoch merkwürdige Sätze, die man so nicht sagen würde, da sich *»blühen«* im Sinne von *»widerfahren«* in der Regel auf (unerfreuliche) Vorgänge bezieht, die noch nicht stattgefunden haben.

Typisches Beispiel:

> Wenn sich Ihr Sohn nicht anstrengt, blüht ihm die Wiederholung der
>   Klasse!

Umformulieren könnte man deine Sätze so:

> Da wurde er in einen Unfall verwickelt. / Hier/dort wurde er in einen Unfall verwickelt.
>
> Er wollte eigentlich Abitur machen, aber dann schlug er eine Karriere
>   als Betonbauer ein.

Answer (score 2):

"Ihm blühte da einen Unfall" ist erstens grammatikalisch falsch.
Wenn dann würde der Satz so lauten:

> Ihm blühte ein Unfall.

Folgende Bedeutung kann man im Duden zu dem Wort blühen finden:
sich prächtig entwickeln.
Bsp: "Der Handel blühte zu jener Zeit."

Das bedeutet, das Wort blühen kannst du streng genommen nicht im Zusammenhang mit einem Unfall verwenden.

> Er ahnt, dass es zu einen Unfall kommen wird.
>   Er ahnt, dass er einen Unfall verursachen wird.

Würden in diesem Zusammenhang besser passen.

Der zweite Satz macht hier schon etwas mehr Sinn. 
Er hatte in Planung, dass er sein Abitur macht aber plötzlich kam im der Gedanke eine Karriere als Betonbauer einzuschlagen. 
Du kannst es dir in etwa so vorstellen:
Du denkst gerade an den Beruf Betonbauer und schlagartig denkst du dir "Dafür bin ich gemacht, meine Qualifikationen sind genau die Ansprüche die dieser Beruf verlangt". 
Sprich du realisierst welche Möglichkeiten dir alles offen stehen wenn du dich dafür entscheidest die Karriere des Betonbauers einzuschlagen.

Vergleichbar wie mit einer Blume, welche zu blühen beginnt, also zu etwas prächtiges heranwächst (z.B. Farbe der Blüte).

Comment: wer "erstens" sagt, muss auch "zweitens" sagen. Mindestens.

Comment: Grammatikalisch falsch? Stilistisch blüht da im Beispiel oben jedenfalls etwas auf einem  von Journalisten oder Romanverfassern erwartbaren Niveau.

Comment: Das Blühen ist auch als Vorbote einer Frucht zu verstehen.

Comment: Wenn im vorhergenden Text von einem Ort die Rede ist (die Nadelöhrkurve in der Höllenschlucht), ist das "da" kein Problem.